# How to listen children's events when children stop propagation

Tags: javascript, html, events, listener, stoppropagation

I need to watch children's events in `Document` level, but if the children stop propagation by using method `stopPropagation()`, I cannot listen those events occur in children.

Can someone know a better way to do this?

---

EDIT: now I want to create an chrome extension to monitor DOM node event, but the event could be stopped propagation, and it is not a good practice to add extra listener to all nodes. Following example will show my question.

**customer HTML fragment**

```
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Click Me" id="b">
</body>
```

**customer javascript**

```
var button = document.querySelector('#b');
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('Button has been clicked');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**chrome extension content scripts**

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('Node(' + e.target.nodeName + ') has been clicked');
  // this listener will not be invoked because event has been stopped
  // propagation.
});
```

Comment: When asking questions here it is always better to describe your real problem, not just the issues with your attempted solution.  That allows people reading your question to offer you solutions you are not even aware of.  When you only describe issues with the solution your tried and have no description of the real problem, there is little we can do beyond the box of the solution you are currently trying to create.  This is known as the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and severely limits how well people can help you.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "capturing" to track an event before bubbling.  There's a very good description of how capturing works (as contrasted with bubbling) in this article: [Bubbling and capturing](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing).

In summary, all browsers except IE before IE9, send events down the chain to the leaf where the event occurred and then they bubble the events back up.  Normal event listening only listens for the event on the actual object or for propagated events, but if you set the third argument to `.addEventListener()` to true, then it will also listen to events going down the chain where the `document` object will see the event FIRST before bubbling has even started or been cancelled.

Here's a working snippet demo:

```js
// show output
function log(x) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = x;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}

// stop propagation on leaf click
var leaf = document.getElementById("leaf");

leaf.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  log("leaf message - click in leaf, propagation stopped")
  e.stopPropagation();
}, false);

// capture listen
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target === leaf) {
   log("document message - click in leaf");
  }
}, true);
```

```html
<div id="topParent">
  <div id="midParent">
    <div id="leaf">
    Click Here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, now I 'm working on chrome extension to monitor DOM event. It is not a good way to add event listener to all DOM nodes, so I need to add the listener in a high level, such as `document`. However, event may be stopped propagation in its own listeners.

Comment: @nailiebreak - What event are you monitoring for and why?

Comment: I have updated my question. Why I need to watch the event in `document` is because I don't know which actual DOM node customer will click or change.

Comment: sorry for forgetting @jfriend00

Comment: @nailiebreak - you still haven't told us what the real problem is that you're trying to solve.  All you've said is that you're trying to intercept clicks everywhere, not what you're really trying to do.  You can literally attach a click handler to every single DOM element and you could monitor the DOM for changes, though I rather doubt you actually need to go that far if we knew the actual problem..

Comment: @nailiebreak - I found a solution to your question and I've rewritten my answer.